# When a batter gets a hit, how does the scoreboard shows that?

Tags: baseball

[Per a tutorial](https://youtu.be/0bKkGeROiPA?t=230),

> A batter **gets a hit** when he reaches a base without getting out or forcing another runner to get out.

When a batter **gets a hit**, how does the scoreboard show that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "it doesn't", at least not the scoreboard you're showing there. This doesn't actually matter, because hits don't win games, runs do.

If you look at the [box score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_score_(baseball)) for a game, you will see that the hits by each player are broken out. Copying from the example on the Wikipedia page and looking at the "h"its column

```
Atlanta Braves     ab  r  h rbi   bb so   po  a
Smith dh            3  1  0   0    1  0    0  0
Pendleton 3b        5  1  4   2    0  0    1  2
<more players>
```

shows that Smith didn't get a hit in that match, but [Pendleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pendleton) got four hits. Similarly, expanded scoreboards at the games will sometimes show things like "4-5" to indicate that Pendleton had 4 hits in 5 at bats.